# Does client-side locking violates encapsulation of synchronization policy?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, encapsulation

As mentioned by [Java_author](https://www.amazon.ca/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Tim-Peierls-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1/138-7375891-1856865),

> Client-side locking entails guarding client code that uses some object X with the lock, X uses to guard its own state.

---

That object X in below code is `list`. Above point says, using lock owned by `ListHelper` type object to synchronize `putIfAbsent()`, is a wrong lock.

```
package compositeobjects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ListHelper<E> {

    private List<E> list =
                    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());


    public boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        synchronized(list){
            boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
            if(absent) {
                list.add(x);
            }
            return absent;
        }
    }
}
```

---

But, Java author says,

> Client-side locking has a lot in common with class extension—they both couple the behavior of the derived class to the implementation of the base class. Just as extension violates encapsulation of implementation [EJ Item 14], client-side locking **violates** encapsulation of synchronization policy.

My understanding is, the nested class instance that `Collections.synchronizedList()` return, also uses lock owned by `list` object.

---

Why usage of client-side locking(with `list`) in `ListHelper`, violates encapsulation of synchronization policy?

Comment: You are relying upon the fact that the `synchronizedList` uses itself as the monitor, which happens to be true at present. If this implementation changed, your code wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Got it. Monitor pattern over `ArrayList` is better idea. Do you suggest?

Comment: You know that your utility class can be replaced by a [`synchronizedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set))?

Comment: "Monitor pattern over ArrayList is better idea. Do you suggest?" No, I'd suggest just doing what you're doing now, because this is well-known behavior that would break *lots* of stuff if it ever changed. You just shouldn't design `synchronizedList` like this if you had to do it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are relying upon the fact that the `synchronizedList` uses itself as the monitor, which happens to be true at present.

You're even relying upon the fact that `synchronizedList` uses `synchronized` to achieve synchronization, which also happens to be true at present (it's a *reasonable* assumption, but it's not one that is necessary).

There are ways in which the implementation of `synchronizedList` could be changed such that your code wouldn't work correctly.

---

For instance, [the constructor of `synchronizedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2398):

```
SynchronizedList(List<E> list) {
  super(list);
  // ...
}
```

could be changed to

```
SynchronizedList(List<E> list) {
  super(list, new Object());
  // ...
}
```

Now, the `mutex` field used by the methods in the `SynchronizedList` implementation is no longer `this` (effectively), so synchronizing externally on `list` would no longer work.

---

*With that said*, the fact that using `synchronized (list)` does have the intended effect is described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)), so this behavior *won't* be changed, so what you are doing now is absolutely fine; it has been designed using a leaky abstraction, and so shouldn't be designed like this if you were doing something similar from scratch, but that leaky abstraction's properties are documented.

Comment: Why would 'if the implementation changed' the code not work correctly? imho the `synchronized(list)` is necessary, otherwise the `Set`-wise operation wouldn't work.

Comment: @M.leRutte think about what would happen if [this line of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2399) changed to `super(list, new Object())` (or [`this line`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2006) changed to `this.mutex = new Object()`). The mutex would no longer be the list itself, so synchronizing on `list` wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, if the list would use a different monitor than `this`, and another thread would access the list, and the sample code would be executed then it would go wrong. I see. Anyway, see my answer, this code is already error prone as it requires all code to go through the utility class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically creates a synchronized set. It only adds elements if it not already in the list, the very definition of a [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Regardless of how the synchronized list does its own locking the code you have must provide its own locking mechanism because there are two calls to the synchronized list, in which between the list will release its lock. So if two threads would add the same object they could both pass the `contains` check and both add it to the list. The compound `synchronize` makes sure that it isn't. Paramount is that all the list usage code goes through your utility class, otherwise it will still fail.

As I have written in an comment, exactly the same behaviour can be achieved with a [`synchronized set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)), which will also make sure that the element has not yet been added while locking the entire operation. By using this synchronized set access and modification without usage of your utility class is ok.

---

Edit:

If your code needs a list and not a set, and a `LinkedHashSet` isn't the option I would create a new synchronized list myself:

```
public class SynchronizedList<E> implements List<E> {
    private List<E> wrapped = new ArrayList<E>();

    ....
    @override
    public int size() {
       synchronized(this) {
          return wrapped.size();
       }
   }

   ....
   @override
   public void add(E element) {
    synchronized(this) {
        boolean absent = !wrapped.contains(x);
        if(absent) {
            wrapped.add(element);
        }
        return absent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I need position based element collection but also `putIfAbsent`. Is that a right usage?

Comment: Would a wrapped [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) suffice? Keeps the order, but it doesn't have a `get(index)`, which I personally rarely need.

Comment: Above use case is about *Adding Functionality to Existing Thread-safe Classes*,  So, *putIfAbsent* is introduced today for the existing `ListHelper<E>`.

Comment: Create a fully wrapped synchronized list? See my edit.

Comment: There is no need to reinvent the wheel by writing your own class. `Collections.synchronizedList` is documented to work in the way OP is using it.

Comment: No, the OP wants to change the semantics of the `add` function (or create a new `putIfAbsent`), in that function a lock needs to be around both the `contains` and `add`, like in the helper class. The `Collections.synchronizedList` does not provide that. Also, the helper class must anyway provide additionional `List` methods, otherwise you cannot access the elements. By having to implement these methods you need to control the locking mechanism to avoid the problem you described.

Comment: @M.leRutte `ListHelper` isn't a `List`. There are no semantics being changed here.